# JAVA - how to save array of Shape to file on desktop?

Tags: java, shapes

I have array of Shape:

```
Shape[] myshape = new Shape[13];
```

How I can save it to file?

I have found some code:

```
String fileName = "file.test";

BufferedOutputStream bs = null;

try {
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
    bs = new BufferedOutputStream(fs);
    bs.write(byte_array);
    bs.close();
    bs = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}

if (bs != null) try { bs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
```

But code work only for byte array, can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to make your Shape class Serializable.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization/447920#447920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Shape[] myshape = new Shape[13];

// populate array

// writing array to disk
FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream("C:\myarray.data");
ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
obj_out.writeObject(array);

// reading array from disk
FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("C:\myarray.data");
ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream (f_in);
Shape[] tmp_array = (Shape[])obj_in.readObject();
```

Comment: Code it OK, but if i read from myarray.data to tmp_array, tmp_array is empty(NULL)...

Comment: Thank you @JaLe29 missed the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use serialization to save the whole object.

Look at the javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

And here a example from stackoverflow:

[serialization/deserialization mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586511/serialization-deserialization-mechanism)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options for saving objects, of which native Java serialisation is one. If you don't want to use serialisation, you could look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which will write POJOs out as XML.

The advantages are that it'll write out human-readable XML, and oyu don't have to implement particular interfaces for your objects. The disadvantage is that XML is relatively verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your shapes to turn them into a byte array.
I don't think Shape implements serializable, so you'll to do that yourself.